# How to get seperate channels in web audio api from <video>?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am trying to get a seperate audio form html  element (file is in mp4 format). File has 6 channel audio and I want to use a PannerNode on each one separately.

So far I am able to create AudioNode from file but I don't know how to get a seperate channels to later use in PannerNode.

```
   var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

   var source = context.createMediaElementSource(video);
```

I know that there is a posiblity to use XMLHttpRequest to get arraybuffer and later use decodeAudioData but I have a problem with testing that. Also It would be prefered to get a file once from HTML video element if that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification for [MediaElementAudioSourceNode](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#mediaelementaudiosourcenode) says this node will have the audio portion of the video source.  To get the individual channels use a `ChannelSplitterNode`.  For example,

```
let splitter = new ChannelSplitterNode(context, {numberOfOutputs: 6});
source.connect(splitter);
```

Now `splitter` has 6 individual outputs, one for each of the channels in your source.  You can now process the individual channels as you see fit.